# How do I change styles in markdown2pdf?

Tags: pdf, miktex, windows, pandoc

I'm a markdown user, and am just getting my feet wet in latex for PDF creation.  I'm using Pandoc and MikTex on Windows 7.  The following command gives me a nice PDF document:

```
markdown2pdf myfile.text
```

How do I change the styles of the PDF?  (Page margin, font size, etc).  I've tried using the "-V" option to add styling information...

```
markdown2pdf -V fontsize=18pt myfile.text
```

...But it doesn't make any difference in the resulting PDF file.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that the options available here are those that the `article` class knows, which is pretty limited. Have you tried using `pandoc` and `pdflatex` separately, and editing the intermediate `.tex`?

Comment: No I have not - but I'll give it a shot.  Ideally though, I'd like the process to be automated, and not have to edit an intermediate `.tex` file each time I want a PDF.

Answer (score 6):

There exists a templating system that comes with `pandoc`, as described in the [User Guide](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html), but see the [Templates](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates) section.

[Kieran Healy](http://www.kieranhealy.org/) has some [nice templates](https://github.com/kjhealy/pandoc-templates) that you could try first, before building your own.

And here is another example with [code on github](http://github.com/karlseguin/the-little-mongodb-book) for [The little MongoDB book](http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf).